# Determine if saving NSManagedObjectContext will result in changes to persistent store

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext

In other words, is it possible to determine if there are changes that would be lost by discarding the current context? Right now my UI indicates the risk of data loss if `context.hasChanges == TRUE`, but I think `hasChanges` looks something like this under the hood:

```
- (BOOL) hasChanges {
    return self.updatedObjects > 0 || self.insertedObjects.count > 0 || self.deletedObjects.count > 0;
}
```

...and `updatedObjects` contains objects that were simply **edited**, even if properties weren't changed from their original values. `updatedObjects` also also contains objects with transient changes. Saving these objects will not modify the persistent store.

I don't want to prompt my users to save if they haven't actually changed anything, so what's the best way to determine if there are changes to persistent properties?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you only care about whether changes exist, rather than finding out exactly what has changed, I'd use the `hasPersistentChangedValues` method on `NSManagedObject` to filter the context's fields. For example,

```
NSPredicate *hasChanges = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"hasPersistentChangedValues = YES"];
BOOL changesExist = ([[context.updatedObjects filteredSetUsingPredicate:hasChanges] count] > 0);
```

The same logic would apply for inserted and deleted objects.

Comment: Good question, I only know about it from this year's WWDC session.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you could use `committedValuesForKeys:` to get the old values of the supposedly-changed keys and compare to the new values. Something like this:

```
@interface NSManagedObject (tofustew)
- (BOOL)isActuallyUpdated;
@end

@implementation NSManagedObject (tofustew)

- (BOOL)isActuallyUpdated {
    NSArray *keys = self.changedValues.keyEnumerator.allObjects;
    NSDictionary *newValues = [self dictionaryWithValuesForKeys:keys];
    NSDictionary *oldValues = [self committedValuesForKeys:self.changedValues.keyEnumerator.allObjects];
    return [oldValues isEqualToDictionary:newValues];
}

@end

@interface NSManagedObjectContext (tofustew)
- (BOOL)hasActualChanges;
@end

@implementation NSManagedObjectContext (tofustew)

- (BOOL)hasActualChanges {
    if (self.insertedObjects.count > 0 || self.deletedObjects.count > 0)
        return YES;
    for (NSManagedObject *object in self.updatedObjects) {
        if (object.isActuallyUpdated) {
            return YES;
        }
    }
    return NO;
}

@end
```

Comment: Oh, interesting - I just posted my own solution below using only the `changedValues` property and based on the Apple docs I think it's does what I need. Will your code produce different results?

Comment: I assumed that setting a property to its existing value marks the object as updated. I haven't verified my assumption.

Comment: Setting a property to its existing value does mark the object as `updated`, but `changedValues` returns an empty set.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up writing the following method in Swift:

```
/// Checks whether there are actually changes that will change the persistent store.
/// The `hasChanges` method would return `true` for transient changes as well which can lead to false positives.
var hasPersistentChanges: Bool {
    return !insertedObjects.isEmpty || !deletedObjects.isEmpty || updatedObjects.first(where: { $0.hasPersistentChangedValues }) != nil
}
```

Combined with the following saveIfNeeded method this leads to only necessarily saves:

```
/// Saves the context, only if it has any changes and if it has a place to save the changes to (parent or persistent store). Calling this method instead of the regular save() will increase performance. It is also useful to use this function when having a memory store, since this configuration doesn't have a persistent store but may use parent contexts to save their changes to.
/// - throws: A Core Data NSError when saving fails.
/// - returns: Whether the save was needed.
@discardableResult public func saveIfNeeded() throws -> Bool {
    let hasPurpose = parent != nil || persistentStoreCoordinator?.persistentStores.isEmpty == false
    guard hasPersistentChanges && hasPurpose else {
        // Saving won't do anything now, except for decreasing performance. Skip it for now.
        return false
    }

    try save()

    return true
}
```

Comment: Nice solution but `persistentStoreCoordinator?.persistentStores.isEmpty` will ever be false?
An in memory store will have at least one NSPersistentStore of type `NSInMemoryStoreType` so the stores list won’t be empty.

Answer (score 0):

This SO post addresses a similar question:

[Identifying which fields have changed before CoreData saves](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5976455/identifying-which-fields-have-changed-before-coredata-saves)

And the relevant Apple docs: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObject_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSManagedObject/changedValues

> This method only reports changes to properties that are defined as
>   persistent properties of the receiver, not changes to transient
>   properties or custom instance variables. This method does not
>   unnecessarily fire relationship faults.

It's as easy as filtering `updatedObjects` like so:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"changedValues[SIZE] > 0"];
NSSet *objectsWithChangedValues = [context.updatedObjects filteredSetUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

A couple lines of code produces the desired result, but I'm still confused as to why `updatedObjects` works the way it does...