# Updating attributes in core data instead of updating the entity

Tags: swift, database, core-data, protocols

I store the employee info in core data in my app. The data from core data will be retrieved and compared with the new student data the following time I connect into the app. I want to update the attribute only if any one of the attributes updated. instead of upgrading the unnecessary entity

```
extension Employee {

    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Employee> {
        return NSFetchRequest<Employee>(entityName: "Employee")
    }

    @NSManaged public var name: String?
    @NSManaged public var state: String?
    @NSManaged public var department: String?
    @NSManaged public var experience: Int16
    @NSManaged public var workingShift: String?

}

extension Employee : Identifiable {

}
```

```
import Foundation

struct EmployeeModel: Identifiable, Hashable, Codable, CustomDebugStringConvertible{
    var debugDescription: String = "debug"
    var id: String
    var name: String
    var state: String
    var department: String
    var workingShift: String
    var experience:Int
    
    
}
extension EmployeeModel{
    static var MOCK_EMPLOYEE: [EmployeeModel] = [
        .init(id: "1", name: "John", state: "Kerala", department: "IOS", workingShift: "General", experience: 1),
        .init(id: "2",name: "Rohit", state: "Maharashtra", department: "Android", workingShift: "AfterNoon", experience: 2),
        .init(id: "3",name: "Aruna", state: "Bihari", department: "Web", workingShift: "Evening", experience: 3),
        .init(id: "4",name: "Abhijeet", state: "WestBengal", department: "Design", workingShift: "Night", experience: 4),
        .init(id: "5",name: "Basivi", state: "Telengana", department: "Game", workingShift: "General", experience: 5),
        .init(id: "6", name: "Andy", state: "Kerala", department: "IOS", workingShift: "General", experience: 1)
        ]
}


extension EmployeeModel{
    func equals (compareTo:EmployeeModel) -> Bool {
           return
               self.name == compareTo.name &&
               self.id == compareTo.id &&
               self.state == compareTo.state &&
        self.department == compareTo.department &&
        self.workingShift == compareTo.workingShift &&
        self.experience == compareTo.experience
       }


     func compareEmployee(lhs: EmployeeModel, rhs: EmployeeModel, completion: @escaping (EmployeeModel) -> Void) {
        var emp = EmployeeModel(id: "", name: "", state: "", department: "", workingShift: "", experience: 0)
        if lhs.id != rhs.id{
            emp.id = rhs.id
        }
        else{
            emp.id = lhs.id
        }
        if lhs.name != rhs.name{
            emp.name = rhs.name
        }
        else{
            emp.name = lhs.name
        }
        if lhs.state != rhs.state{
            emp.state = rhs.state
        }
        else{
            emp.state = lhs.state
        }
        if lhs.department != rhs.department{
            emp.department = rhs.department
        }
        else{
            emp.department = lhs.department
        }
        if lhs.workingShift != rhs.workingShift{
            emp.workingShift = rhs.department
        }
        else{
            emp.workingShift = lhs.workingShift
        }
        if lhs.experience != rhs.experience{
            emp.experience = rhs.experience
        }
        else{
            emp.experience = lhs.experience
        }
        completion(emp)
       }
}
```

```
   // MARK: - Core Data stack
    func checkDataStore() {
        let emp: Employee!
        let fetchUser: NSFetchRequest<Employee> = Employee.fetchRequest()
        //        fetchUser.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name = %@", name as String)
        let moc = coredata.persistentContainer.viewContext
        
        
        let results = try? moc.fetch(fetchUser)
        
        
        do {
            if results!.count == 0{
                emp = Employee(context: moc)
                
                if let firstEmp = EmployeeModel.MOCK_EMPLOYEE[0] as? EmployeeModel{
                    emp.state = firstEmp.state
                    emp.name = firstEmp.name
                    emp.department = firstEmp.department
                    emp.workingShift = firstEmp.workingShift
                    emp.experience = Int16(firstEmp.experience)
                    
                }
            }
            else{
                let emp1 = EmployeeModel.MOCK_EMPLOYEE[0]
                let emp2 = EmployeeModel.MOCK_EMPLOYEE[4]
                
                emp1.compareEmployee(lhs: emp1, rhs: emp2) { resultModel in
                    if emp1 == resultModel{
                        print("No changes made")
                    } else {
                        print("Changes made. Updating server.")
                        results![0].state = resultModel.state
                        results![0].name = resultModel.name
                        results![0].department = resultModel.department
                        results![0].workingShift = resultModel.workingShift
                        results![0].experience = Int16(resultModel.experience)
                        
                    }
                }
            }
            
            
        coredata.saveContext()
        
    }
    catch {
        fatalError("Error in counting home record")
    }

}
```

Is it the correct way I am doing the code or is there any other way to do it?

The result I was hoping for is happening. But I'm curious whether there's another, more straightforward solution. We can do this because of the structure's simplicity. if the response is massive and nested. What were we able to do at the time?

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the NSManagedObject properties

```
hasPersistentChangedValues
```

or

```
hasChanges
```

In your case:

```
emp.hasPersistentChangedValues
```

or

```
emp.hasChanges
```

So if you change your object **emp** attribute.
CoreData will mark the object as changed. The object will has flag **hasChanges** true. Even if you assign property to old value by yourself.

But the flag **hasPersistentChangedValues** will show whether you object has changes with the object stored on disk or no. Even if you assign attribute back again

Also check the answer

[hasPersistentChangedValues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33311101/determine-if-saving-nsmanagedobjectcontext-will-result-in-changes-to-persistent)

Comment: After comparing both of the models, how can I find the particular attribute("Key-Value") is changed? If it is a nested and large structure, I cannot compare the attributes one by one. So is there any way to compare the two structures the particular attribute can be found? I am talking about "compareEmployee" function.

Comment: Your EmployeeModel is a Struct. You should change it to class inherited from NSObject to get Key Value Observing.